# Custom sass with Ts variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I'm working on an Angular project and I have three cards and a progress bar inside.
The operation for getting the % is here

```
cards.component.ts

nbLessonsFinish(){
  return 3 //My future code here (boolean)
}

nbLessonsInChapter(){
  return 10 //My future code here (boolean)
}

percentage(){
  let prc = (( this.nbLessonsFinish() / this.nbLessonsInChapter()) * 100)
  return prc //Percent to set in scss 
}

 cards.component.scss

.CSS svg circle:nth-child(2) {
stroke-dashoffset: calc(865 - (865 * (my-ts-variable))/ 100);
}

.HTML svg circle:nth-child(2) {
stroke-dashoffset: calc(865 - (865 * (my-ts-variable)) / 100);
}

.ALGORITHMIQUE svg circle:nth-child(2) {
stroke-dashoffset: calc(865 - (865 * (my-ts-variable)) / 100);
}
```

My question is : How can I pass the 'prc' in .ts to .scss ? And if I can't how can i resolve this ??

Extra :
[image: My cards]
Hope it was clear , thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: You can't. Both SCSS and TypeScript are evaluated at compile-time, and you're trying to include a runtime value.

Comment: You cannot modify a css class on runtime, but you can update the element style directly.

Comment: so what are you trying to do? Angular can use selective css to apply different css under different circumstance

Comment: @MarkHomer I'm trying to update the progression bar depending on the progression of user but my calculation is in the .scss If the user complete a course in HTML for example the the calculation sass change. I don't know if i can use ngClass or ngStyle for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ngclass to apply different css for different conditions, as you dont provide much info I will just give you idea how it works

```
<div [ngClass]="{'classname' : condition}"></div>
```

so something like

```
<div [ngClass]="{'CSS': percentage() === 40, 
                 'HTML': percentage() === 60, 
                 'ALGORITHMIQUE': percentage() === 100}"></div>
```